# JQuery files NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why but when I create a JQuery file in http://www.codecademy.com/learn it does work amazingly; but when I upload and run it on altervista.org/ I just can't understand why it doesn't neither read it!

I first forgot to implement JQuery, but after that I added this line of code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
```

it still doesn't seem to be read.

I'm leaving you my JS file here, hope it might be helpful :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
$(document).keydown(function(key) {

    var tleft = $('#char').position().left;
    var wleft = $('#rectw').position().left;
    var lleft = $('#rectl').position().left;
    var lleft_1 = $('#rectl_1').position().left;
    var lleft_2 = $('#rectl_2').position().left;

    var ttop = $('#char').position().top;
    var wtop = $('#rectw').position().top;
    var ltop = $('#rectl').position().top;
    var ltop_1 = $('#rectl_1').position().top;
    var ltop_2 = $('#rectl_2').position().top;

    var lost = 0;
    var won = 0;


    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        // Left arrow key pressed
        case 65:
            $('#char').animate({left: "-=50px"}, 'fast');
            var tleft = $('#char').position().left - 50;
            break;
        // Up Arrow Pressed
        case 87:
            $('#char').animate({top: "-=50px"}, 'fast');
            var ttop = $('#char').position().top - 50;
            break;
        // Right Arrow Pressed
        case 68:
            $('#char').animate({left: "+=50px"}, 'fast');
            var tleft = $('#char').position().left + 50;

            break;
        // Down Arrow Pressed
        case 83:
            $('#char').animate({top: "+=50px"}, 'fast');
            var ttop = $('#char').position().top + 50;
            break;
        //Jump
        case 32:
            $('#char').animate({top: "-=50px"}, 'fast');
            $('#char').animate({top: "+=50px"}, 'fast');
            break;

    }



if(tleft === wleft && ttop === wtop){
        alert("You Win!");
}
else if(tleft === lleft && ttop === ltop){
    alert("You Lose!");
}
else if(tleft === lleft_1 && ttop === ltop_1){
    alert("You Lose!");
}
else if(tleft === lleft_2 && ttop === ltop_2){
    alert("You Lose!");
}

});
});
```

//HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Super Mario!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css.css'/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='inc/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: are there any error messages in your browser's console?

Comment: Yes: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Which resource was not found? jQuery itself? You should definitely be using a newer version of jQuery

Comment: Yes I guess so, it neither reads it

Comment: Probably, that's what I tought. But, how to see what's my running version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download a copy for your local machine and use a newer version. Then you can create a fallback to your jQuery source:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Super Mario!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css.css'/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='path/to/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
```

If the CDN fails this fallback will seek and load the local copy of jQuery.

Comment: Please edit your original post with any updated information @LeonardoFettucciari

Comment: I don't see any updates to your original post @LeonardoFettucciari

Comment: I have provided the link to my code in the bottom, so you can check all the HTML, CSS and Javascript files :) @JayBlanchard

Comment: You actually need to update your post @LeonardoFettucciari so the question and answers can be preserved for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Not the URL @LeonardoFettucciari, the actual code. A URL is not sufficient here.

Comment: Okay, give me a second and I'll update my post with all the code needed

Comment: Only include the relevant code @LeonardoFettucciari

Comment: Done, the JS is all needed and for the HTML I've updated it on the Head tag only

Comment: *You haven't made any changes from what we can see.* Have you included the fallback that I have shown you? Have you downloaded jQuery?

Comment: This is what I figured out thanks to a lesson on your website

Comment: You're loading your scripts *before* the jQuery. Change the order like I have them in my updated answer. Your scripts have to be loaded *after* the jQuery is loaded @LeonardoFettucciari

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I can't even think that I made such that mistake, but at least now I won't do that twice! :) @JayBlanchard